# plotting a curve between two given cordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

If I am given x<sub>0</sub>,y<sub>0</sub> and x<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>1</sub> as starting and ending point coordinates to draw a curve(parabola), what will be the value of y for every corresponding x value if i increase the value of x by 1

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here. You're saying you can draw any curve? Do you mean a line? Otherwise, you could draw some random squiggly curve than connects the two points.

Comment: parabolic curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this problem has infinite solutions. To give you an example, I will assume $(x_0, y_0) = (0, 0)$ and $(x_1, y_1) = (1,1)$, a parabola of the form

$$
y= ax^2 + bx + c
$$

Note that when you evaluate $(x_0,y_0)$ you get $c = 0$, if you evaluate $(x_1, y_1)$ you get

$$
y = ax(x - 1) + x
$$

where $a$ can take any value. Here's an example

[image]